# MapIndexed on a table of SparseArray structures produces different output in Mathematica 12 and 14.0

Tags: sparse-arrays, mapindexed

Here is a snippet I use to dynamically define a bunch of functions `f[i][x_]`:

```
Clear[f];
tabrhs = {SparseArray[{1, 1} -> Sin[x]], SparseArray[{1, 1} -> Cos[x]]};
MapIndexed[(f[First[#2]][x_] := #1) &, tabrhs];
```

In Mathematica 12, this produces the desired output:

```
f[1][z] (* SparseArray[{1,1} -> Sin[z]] *)
f[2][z] (* SparseArray[{1,1} -> Cos[z]] *)
```

In Mathematica 14.0, this produces instead:

```
f[1][z] (* SparseArray[{1,1} -> Sin[x]] *)
f[2][z] (* SparseArray[{1,1} -> Cos[x]] *) (* notice the 'x' instead of 'z' *)
```

Note that if I do not use SparseArray structures and instead use the simpler:

```
Clear[f];
tabrhs = {Sin[x], Cos[x]};
MapIndexed[(f[First[#2]][x_] := #1) &, tabrhs];
```

The result is consistent in both versions:

```
f[1][z] (* Sin[z] *)
f[2][z] (* Cos[z] *)
```

I do care for the SparseArray structure, though. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear[f];
tabrhs={SparseArray[{1,1}->Sin[x]],SparseArray[{1,1}->Cos[x]]};
MapIndexed[(f[First[#2]][t_]:=SparseArray[ArrayRules[#1]/.x->t])&,tabrhs];
f[1][y]//Normal
```

> {{Sin[y]}}

Update:

```
Clear[f];
tabrhs={SparseArray[{1,1}->Sin[x]],SparseArray[{1,1}->Cos[x]]};
MapIndexed[(f[First[#2]]=SparseArray@*(Function@@{x,ArrayRules@#1}))&,tabrhs];
f[1][y] // Normal
```

> {{Sin[y]}}

Update 2:

```
Clear[f];
tabrhs={SparseArray[{1,1}->Sin[x]],SparseArray[{_,_}->0,{1,1}]};
MapIndexed[(f[First[#2]]=SparseArray@@#&@*(Function@@{x,{ArrayRules@#1,Dimensions@#1}}))&,tabrhs];
f[1][y]//Normal
f[2][y]//Normal
```

> {{Sin[y]}}

> {{0}}

Comment: That works. Follow up: is there a way to make that work with a `Set` (=) instead of `SetDelayed` (:=) ?

Comment: Also, I'm actually not a fan of the replace rule, as this does not work out of the box in an external package where the `t` would be interpreted as `package'Private't`, and not amenable to patterns.

Comment: @jrekier Updated.

Comment: Yup, that works. Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes `tabrhs` contains empty arrays. e.g. `SparseArray[{_,_}->0,{1,1}]`.
Any idea how to adapt your function to transfer the dimension info to `f`?

Comment: @jrekier Updated 2.

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks